# How to create a pop-up window (link a MainWindow with a Dialog) in Qt Designer (Python)?

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I'm trying to build an "About" dialog window for my app. My main window is a "MainWindow" type and the "About" window is a Dialog, both created with QT Designer and transformed to ".py" files with pyuic4 --> gui_v1.py and about_v1.py

In my the main file of my app, I built this second class for the about dialog:

```
import gui_v1
import about_v1

class AboutDialog(QtGui.QDialog, about_v1.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AboutDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

I added the open_about() function to my main class in the main file, and linked this function to the menu button responsible for opening the about window:

```
class MainDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow, gui_v1.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.pyqtRemoveInputHook()

        [...]

        def open_about(self):
           app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
           form = AboutDialog()
           form.show()
           app.exec_()
```

My main app is running from this last function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def main():
        app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        form=MainDialog()
        form.show()
        app.exec_()

    main()
```

When clicking on the About menu item, nothing happens. I'm guessing the problem is in the open_about() function, but I can't seem to find what it is. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

QMessageBox has some built in about box functionality.   Look at

```
QMessageBox.about (QWidget parent, QString caption, QString text)
```

So you would call it something like:

```
QMessageBox.about (self, "About whatever....", "The text you want to display in the box")
```

You can look at the QMessageBox documentation here:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html